# Proof of the Hamiltonian slice theorem

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, group-actions

> Theorem(Guillemin Sternberg Marle) Let $(M, \omega, \mu) $ be a symplectic manifold together with a Hamiltonian group action. Let $p$ be a point in $M$ such that  $O_p $ is contained in the zero level set of the moment map. Denote $G_p$ the stabilizer and $O_p$ the orbit of $p$. There is a $G$-equivariant symplectomorphism from a neighborhood of the zero section of the bundle $T^*G ×_{G_p} V_p$  equiped with a symplectic  model to a neighborhood  of the orbit $O_p$.

I'm looking for a reference of this theorem. ( The references that people recommend are the articles of Marle which is written in french and the article The normal form for the moment map by Guillemin and Sternberg which I can't download from internet). Could you please give some references where I can find the proof of this theorem.

Comment: I think it is covered in section 41, Symplectic slices and moment reconstruction, starting on p. 324 of Guillemin and Sternberg, Symplectic Techniques in Physics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following textbooks contain a proof of the symplectic slice theorem:

- [Juan-Pablo Ortega and Tudor S. Ratiu: Momentum Maps and Hamiltonian Reduction](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3811-7)
- [Gerd Rudolph and Matthias Schmidt: Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-007-5345-7)

You might also have a look at my [PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00744). One of the main results is a symplectic slice theorem in infinite dimensions. Thus there also a lot of analytical questions that need to be answered, so maybe not the best point to start learning this topic.

Comment: .@Tobias Diez, thanks a lot for your helful answer!